# What does “channelling the spirit of” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Much of the exquisite joy of Balls’s Strictly tenure was found in the distinct dearth of damns he gave about holding back or saving face. He lost himself in every song slung in his direction. On week two, there was not a viewer in Britain unclear that Balls was channelling the spirit of a gadabout Charleston dancing, gingham-shirt clad farmhand.

channelling the spirit of = is being inspired by?

Comment: Is it "sung" or  "slung"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its most literal sense, the expression 'channel the spirit of' means to allow the spirit of a dead person to speak using your voice, as some people (such as mediums) claim to be able to do. For example:

> She claims to channel the spirit of a 2,000-year-old hunter.

However, the expression is being used in a more figurative sense here. Unless I'm mistaken, the paragraph in question is from an [article](http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/ed-balls-strictly-come-dancing-politics-donald-trump-nigel-farage-samba-a7443686.html) about Ed Balls appearance on the TV show "Strictly Come Dancing' - an article that gives a less than flattering account of Mr. Balls's performances. In [one those performances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqPaaf1dB4U), he and Katya Jones dance the Charleston. Therefore the article is saying, figuratively of course, that the spirit of a 'gingham-shirt clad farmhand' is speaking through him.

In essence, it means that he is acting (and dancing) like an unsophisticated country person.